# Does anyone know this chip? "38 LP"

Tags: identification

I have a s-video to digital board that has a 8-pin SMD chip with code "38 LP" and the Analog Devices logo on it.  How can I find its datasheet?

I searched the Analog Devices site and alldatasheet site, but I didn't find anything.
Thanks
[image: 38 LP]

Comment: did you ask this before?

Comment: Yes, but I added the picture of the chip to the question.

Comment: Plaese also show the complete board!

Comment: @M.AliSafdari you should have added pictures to the first question ... do not open a new question ... edit the question